# ASP-Controller adds API as prefix of route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have following tag in .net core's "_Layout.cshtml"

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Work" asp-action="Index">Work</a>
```

On runtime it is converted to following.

```
<a href="/api/Work/Index">Work</a>
```

Why it is adding "api"? How can I write without that?

I need following output as a link.

```
<a href="/Work/Index">Work</a>
```

Comment: The controller `Work` is in Area?

Comment: no. even if I remove it. it remains same.

Comment: the `api` in the route is the default for web api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1#routing-and-url-paths

Comment: we need to set default through routeconfig. otherwise it will not be default. but still, it should not affect this tag.

Comment: You want to change the route?

Comment: My hyperlink should be created like "<a href="/Work/Index">Work</a>" currently it is creating "<a href="/api/Work/Index">Work</a>".

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent `api` to be added to the route, as this is part of how the route is constructed.

The only way to write the url is to don't use the helpers:

```
<a href="/work/index">Work</a>
```

Comment: Ya. I could do that. Just wanted to know why is this happening.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator The `api` is prepended because you're having your controller routed with `api/[controller]`.The url generation will take that in consideration and resulting a leading 'api' in your generated url.